# Java format double to string with minimal precision

Tags: java, formatting, double, precision

How to get double value printed in formatted string with minimal precision? Example:

```
double v = 2.02;
String.format("%f", v);
```

Default `%f` format always prints [6 digits after point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) => "2.020000". What I need is

```
42.0  => "42"
2.02  => "2.02"
0.3333333333333333 => "0.3333333333333333"
```

The best I can get so far is `String.valueOf(v)`

```
String.format("%s", String.valueOf(v));
```

That pass all tests except "42". Any ideas on **easy way** to do all three tests?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Yassin, there is a ggod way by custom formatted:

```
public static String fmt(double d)
{
    if(d == (long) d)
        return String.format("%d",(long)d);
    else
        return String.format("%s",d);
}
```

Comment: `String.format("%s",d)`??? Talk about unnecessary overhead. Use `Double.toString(d)`. Same for the other: `Long.toString((long)d)`.